# Strange behaviour in Get request

Tags: java, shopify

NOTE: This contains fixed code.

The following get request works:

```
curl https://9d3d9934609d1a7d79865231be1ecb23:9432fb76a34a0d46d64a2f4cf81bebd6@smartprice-2.myshopify.com/admin/orders.json
```

But the following code in java that I though did the same returns a 401.

```
        final String url = "https://9d3d9934609d1a7d79865231be1ecb23:9432fb76a34a0d46d64a2f4cf81bebd6@smartprice-2.myshopify.com/admin/orders.json";
        final HttpURLConnection con = (HttpURLConnection) new URL(url).openConnection();
        con.setRequestMethod("GET");
        con.setRequestProperty("User-Agent", USER_AGENT);
        con.setRequestProperty("Content-Type", "application/json");
        final String encoded = Base64.encodeBase64String((api+":"+pass).getBytes());
        con.setRequestProperty("Authorization", "Basic "+encoded);

        System.out.println("\nSending 'GET' request to URL : " + url);
        int responseCode = con.getResponseCode();
        System.out.println("Response Code : " + responseCode);
```

What am I missing here?
Are those not identical?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

401 means unauthorized. Nothing surprising. The thing is that curl is able to resolve username:password used in your URL (part before '@' sign) and append it automatically as **Authorization** header in your request. But Java API is not doing this so you will have to do it on your own. The best way to investigate is to run curl with -v option. In it, you will see something like:

```
* Server auth using Basic with user '9d3d9934609d1a7d79865231be1ecb23'
> GET /admin/orders.json HTTP/1.1
> Host: smartprice-2.myshopify.com
> Authorization: Basic OWQzZDk5MzQ2MDlkMWE3ZDc5ODY1MjMxYmUxZWNiMjM6OTQzMmZiNzZhMzRhMGQ0NmQ2NGEyZjRjZjgxYmViZDY=
> User-Agent: curl/7.44.0
> Accept: */*
```

So you can notice that curl automatically appends HTTP Basic Authorization header to your request. So the correct Java code would be:

```
final String url = "https://smartprice-2.myshopify.com/admin/orders.json";
final HttpsURLConnection con = (HttpsURLConnection) new URL(url).openConnection();
con.setRequestProperty("Authorization", "Basic OWQzZDk5MzQ2MDlkMWE3ZDc5ODY1MjMxYmUxZWNiMjM6OTQzMmZiNzZhMzRhMGQ0NmQ2NGEyZjRjZjgxYmViZDY=");
con.setRequestMethod("GET");
System.out.println("Response Code : " + con.getResponseCode());
```

You can notice, that there is no reason to use credentials in URL and use only Authorization header (request property). By the way if you decode Base64: `OWQzZDk5MzQ2MDlkMWE3ZDc5ODY1MjMxYmUxZWNiMjM6OTQzMmZiNzZhMzRhMGQ0NmQ2NGEyZjRjZjgxYmViZDY=`, you will get exactly the part of URL before '@' which is: `9d3d9934609d1a7d79865231be1ecb23:9432fb76a34a0d46d64a2f4cf81bebd6`

If you want automatic way how to resolve your Authorization header, you can use

```
final String credentials = DatatypeConverter.printBase64Binary("username:password".getBytes());
con.setRequestProperty("Authorization", "Basic " + credentials);
```

Comment: Thanks for the quick response. Makes sense.

Comment: You are welcome, it took a while to me before I noticed that URI has credentials in it :-)

Answer (score 2):

401 error stands for the Unauthorized access.

You need to either use Authenticator:

```
Authenticator.setDefault (new Authenticator() {
    protected PasswordAuthentication getPasswordAuthentication() {
        return new PasswordAuthentication ("username", "password".toCharArray());
    }
});
```

or set a property:

```
String basicAuth = "Basic " + new String(new Base64().encode(userpass.getBytes()));
con.setRequestProperty ("Authorization", basicAuth);
```